# Перезагрузить страницу пользователя ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

Некоторые наши пользователи до сих пор используют старую версию сайта (возможно, в браузере не закрыта вкладка). Эта версия сайта(старая) делает Ajax вызов на наш веб-сервер и вставляет ответ в виде строки (без Eval (), т.е. JS код не отрабатывает).

Есть какой-либо способ, чтобы перезагрузить эту страницу с нашего сервера?

Пример скрипта у пользователя:

```
function openPOST(url, params, callback) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-rlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(params);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                    if (callback) callback(this.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    };

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ...
        function go() {
            openPOST("/home/someaction", "query=123", function (count) {
                document.querySelector("h1").textContent = count;
            });
        }
        ...
        go();
        ...
});
```

Пробовал подменить старый экшен на этот.

```
public void someaction() {
                Response.Status = "307 Temporary Redirect";
                Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://example.com");
            }
```

Вместо желаемой перезагрузки страницы, весь код страницы `http://example.com`  вставляется в `document.querySelector("h1").textContent`